# conditional build based on branch for multi stage pipeline using different templates under stages

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-yaml-pipelines

How to trigger by branch to use specific template under "stages"?

trigger:

```
 branches

   include:

     - ci

     - prod
```

stages:

- template: ci.yml

  condition: and(eq(['build.sourceBranch'], 'ci'))
- template: prod.yml

  condition: and(eq(['build.sourceBranch'], 'prod'))

Tried above condition but didn't work. I was getting "unexpected value condition". Any help is appreciated

***** Tried one of the solution as by passing condition as parameter to the template:

stages:

- template: ci.yml

  parameters:

  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/ci'))
- template: prod.yml

  parameters:

  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/prod'))

Getting "unexpected parameter condition"

Pipeline structure:

**master.yml (contains runtime parameters)**
stages:

template: ci.yml

parameters:

condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/ci'))

template: prod.yml

parameters:

condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/prod'))

**ci.yml**

stages:

- stage: BuildApp
- stage: BuildWeb
- stage: DeployLocal

**prod.yml**

stages:

- stage: BuildApp
- stage: BuildWeb
- stage: DeployProd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to trigger by branch to use specific template under "stages"?

To resolve this issue, we could add the **condition on the job level,** like:

```
stages:
- stage: Test1
  jobs:
  - job: ci
    displayName: ci
    pool:
      name: MyPrivateAgent
    condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/ci'))
    steps:
        - template: ci.yml

  - job: prod
    displayName: prod
    pool:
      name: MyPrivateAgent
    condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/prod'))
    steps:
        - template: prod.yml
```

Check the document [Specify conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#how-can-i-trigger-a-job-if-a-previous-job-succeeded-with-issues) for some more details.

On the other hand, we could also set the condition as parameter to the template yml, like:

```
- template: ci.yml
  parameters:
    doTheThing: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/ci'))
```

The template yml file:

```
# template.yml
parameters:
  doTheThing: 'false'
steps:
- script: echo This always happens!
  displayName: Always
- script: echo Sometimes this happens!
  condition: ${{ parameters.doTheThing }}
  displayName: Only if true
```

You could check the thread [YAML - Support conditions for templates](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/issues/1749) for some more details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the pointers. I have updated my question with one of the solutions i tried.

Comment: @iab., Share your yaml file, please.

Comment: Can we pass the parameters in condition to a template under stages?

Comment: added the skeleton template if that helps

Comment: @iab., I'm sorry that can't provide effective help. Because your error is a yml syntax error, and yml is a strict indented syntax, we need the content of your yml file, otherwise we cannot help you find the cause of the error. You can share your yaml file, hide your personal information or use other characters instead of like xx.

Comment: @iab., Yes, we could pass the parameters in condition to a template under stages

Comment: No worries. Thank you for your help. I tried passing parameters to condition under stages and was able to get the first yml working but the second template for different branch was having issue so i thought to not complicate i moved all the stage's out of template into master yml which resolved my issue.